# ERROR: relation "name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, import

I am trying to import a postgresql database table sent to me in phpPgAdmin, I am following the instruction from this [import database](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/postgresql/import-database)

But after doing so, several error appear, I also tried to import the database using cmd but the same error continues to persist

```
DROP TABLE
postgresql.sql:33: ERROR: relation "accessories_id_seq" does not exist
postgresql.sql:34: ERROR: relation "public.accessories" does not exist
BEGIN
postgresql.sql:40: ERROR: relation "public.accessories" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "public"."accessories" VALUES ('1', 'Vario V8', ...
^
postgresql.sql:41: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I researched the problem here in stackoverflow but people who had the same error are making new database tables and and thus most of the errors comes from mixed-case spelling, I'm just pulling data from a database sent to me.
Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

In cmd I used this command

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%/Postgresql/9.3/bin/psql.exe" -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres -d postgres -a -f C:/Sites/xmastool/postgresql.sql
```

The file is an SQL file

After removing all the drop statements this error now appears

```html
postgresql.sql:33: ERROR: syntax error at or near ""
LINE 1: /*
^
postgresql.sql:34: ERROR: relation "public.accessories" does not exist
BEGIN
postgresql.sql:40: ERROR: relation "public.accessories" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "public"."accessories" VALUES ('1', 'Vario V8', ...
^
```

This is the first lines of the code

```html
/*
 Navicat Premium Data Transfer

 Source Server         : 
 Source Server Type    : PostgreSQL
 Source Server Version : 90207
 Source Host           : 
 Source Database       : foo
 Source Schema         : public

 Target Server Type    : PostgreSQL
 Target Server Version : 90207
 File Encoding         : utf-8

 Date: 11/19/2014 15:42:40 PM
*/

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for accessories
-- ----------------------------

CREATE TABLE "public"."accessories" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('accessories_id_seq'::regclass),
    "accessory_name" varchar(255) DEFAULT ''::character varying COLLATE "default",
    "accessory_description" text COLLATE "default",
    "accessory_size" varchar(255) DEFAULT ''::character varying COLLATE "default",
    "created_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "price" varchar(255) DEFAULT '0.00'::character varying COLLATE "default",
    "active" int4 DEFAULT 1,
    "img_url" varchar(255) DEFAULT ''::character varying COLLATE "default"
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "public"."accessories" OWNER TO "gptpgsxlzwywhc";

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of accessories
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "public"."accessories" VALUES ('');
```

Comment: It sounds like that the dump is somehow incomplete.  It would be interesting to see the original command used for taking the dump.  Also, possibly showing the top 40 line if the dump could help in helping you.

Comment: @dezso : I added the first lines of code but that was after I removed the DROP statement

Comment: You mention `postgresql.sql:33: ERROR: syntax error at or near "" LINE 1: /*` - I see no `/*` anywhere.

Comment: @dezso : Oh, my bad. I edited my post.

Comment: If this really starts like that, than there should be an error saying `ERROR:  relation "accessories_id_seq" does not exist`

Comment: That was the first error but after removing the **DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."accessories";**  and all the other drop statements it was removed and was replaced by the next error I posted.